# storing tuples of 2 ints and a char in an NSArray,

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray

I want to store tuples of 2 ints and a char in an NSArray.
Is there an easyer way than to declare an class holding the 2 ints and the char?

I tryed it this way and it works, but it seems rather complicated to me. Is there a better and easyer way?

```
@interface Container : NSObject
@property  NSInteger a;
@property  NSInteger b;
@property  char      c;
@end

@implementation Container
@synthesize a = _a;
@synthesize b = _b;
@synthesize c = _c;

-(Container*) initWitha:(NSInteger) a andB:(NSInteger) b andC: (char) c
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.a = a;
        self.b = b;
        self.c = c;
    }
    return self;
}  
@end

...
//usage

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject: [[Container alloc] initWitha:5 andB:6 andC:'D']];
```

Thanks

Comment: Your init method will need `if ((super = [super init]))`

Comment: NSArray can hold only objects, so your best bet is to create a C array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could just use a C struct ?

```
struct Container {
    NSInteger a; // If you're using char c, why not use int a?
    NSInteger b;
    char c;
};
```

then you could do something like

```
struct Container c;

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]

// Insert
[array addObject:[NSValue value:&c withObjCType:@encode(struct Container)]];

// Retrieve:
struct Container c;
[[array objectAtIndex:i] getValue:&c];
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple recommends that you do not evaluate `self` in the constructors at the same time as assigning it `[super init]`.

Your init method will need to read:

```
-(Container *) initWitha:(NSInteger) a andB:(NSInteger) b andC: (char) c
{ 
    self = [super init];

    if ( self != nil ) {
        self.a =a;
        self.b=b;
        self.c=c;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Would you happen to have a link to where it says this in the docs?

Comment: [This doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html) gives an example which contradicts your statement.

Comment: And if you want to apply good practices, then _guarding_ is preferable to nesting: `if (!(self = [super init])) { return nil; } _a = a; _b = b; _c = c; return self;`. Also, method name in ObjC should be `initWithA:b:c:`.